# writing commands in order ( Linux )

Tags: python, linux, command-line, terminal

i'm new to Linux.

I am learning Linux commands.
I am looking for a way to write command lines after each other from text file for instance.
Instead of typing five or more lines by self i can just call the text file to write commands after each other.
Is this even possible?
Is this a known thing? 
If there is anything like please guide me to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the guys at ServerFault might be better suited to answer this question.

Comment: Are you trying to invent shell scripts? Commands are usually stored in a file,  typically with filename extension `.sh` and then invoked as `sh filename.sh` (replace filename with your script's name).

Comment: I think you need to load the text line by line in terminal, be able to amend them as needed and then execute them. If no intervention is needed it makes no difference if lines are loaded one by one or not. If your file is not a series of bash instructions but just a large text maybe you want to see it page by page with a for loop or dir | more if you are listing a directory. Please be more specific, try to explain why you need one line at a time. Your solution might be: for line in $ (cat file.txt) do echo "$ line" done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create it by using the `subprocess` module.

Example :

```python
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["ls"])
subprocess.call(["touch","helloworld.txt"])

# You can enter commands by using subprocess.call()
```

The you use   `chmod +x filename.py` to make the file executable and the  `./filename.py` to run the script

Or as suggested by @bipll in the comments, creating an `.sh` file. Here is the [tutorial if you need.](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Hello,_World!_Tutorial)

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for thanks everyone